# Visual Studio 2010 - C/C++ - Intellisense - Paramater Types and Names vs just Names

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

Trying to get myself back learning C++ in Visual Studio 2010 and I just noticed this.

How come these are different?
GetWindowRect function call will show you the parameter types and names
  -- but --
CreateWindow function call will only show you the parameter names

Comment: see how they are declared in the .h files. both have names and types?

Comment: Right click on function + go to definition. CreateWindow may have been redifined as a macro or something?

Comment: And think this tracks back to #define CreateWindowW(lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)\
CreateWindowExW(0L, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,\
nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam)

Comment: Thanks, Tom Fobear. If you can put the answer in I can give you credit.